# Django : Use decorator 'user_passes_test' using LDAP group witout django DB

Tags: django, django-models, ldap, django-auth-ldap

I want to use LDAP AUTH for django.
For the moment I have also a django Model Backend where are all my users and theirs groups.

In my code, an user passes a test in order to access to application. This operation check if the group to allow is in the user information.

But now I wanted to stop using Model Authentication and use only LDAP AUTH...

How can I manage to use the same function to allow access, with LDAP groups without creating an user in the Model?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about LDAP is general, but you can follow this tutorial on how to login to LDAP using Python :  http://blog.emfeld.com/2013/03/ldap-login-authentication-using-python.html

Once you understand the basics, you can implement login in Django.

Hint : You will have to update the code of the login view. After getting the username and the password from the form, it will now search in LDAP instead of models